# The answer that I'd like to post doesn't really answer the question, but

Tags: discussion, answers

I know that the answer really gets to the heart of what the OP was going for - 'cause it's my question. It seems like forever ago that I asked this: [Using toasted sesame oil in a cilantro "pesto"?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36809/using-toasted-sesame-oil-in-a-cilantro-pesto). Well after almost three months of playing with it, I have a cilantro condiment that makes me very happy and lasts and lasts. However, it doesn't contain sesame oil and bears no resemblance to a pesto. I'd like to share it though, its longevity makes it really nice to have on hand if you're a cilantro lover. Whats the best way to play this?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this is hard to answer because your original question was very vague, pretty much "I want something for this purpose, here's a random idea, what do you think?" To my reading, it's bordering on broad enough to be closed, and what you ended up with would certainly fall within the field of possible answers.

Probably the best thing to do would be to post your answer, explaining *why* you didn't do what you originally suggested ("the pesto idea doesn't work well because..."), and if necessary tweak your question to make it clear what the OP was actually going for. When you ask a question, it's up to you to make sure the intent matches the wording. It'd be better if you'd done that earlier, but you can still edit it.

Comment: Ok, so I'll add an edit, an addendum, to the question, then post what I came up with as an answer. I'll leave the text as-is in the question so the responses make sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Jolenealaska It is *far* better to tweak the existing question so that it includes other answers and yours (though again, the question as written is extremely broad and includes just about everything anyone could think to say about Asian cilantro condiments). Tacked-on edits just make the question even harder to read for anyone else trying to answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll try then. I might try to catch you after playing with it but before hitting "Post".

Comment: @Jolenealaska I'd just edit it, so everyone can look and see if they like it if they want. Keep in mind, all you're trying to do is edit the question so that it actually asks what you meant to ask in the first place. It's just a clarification.